# how to define a pointer in a string and make it as a start point? (based on K&R C exercise 5-4)

Tags: c

I am learning C language based on the book K&R 2nd edition, when tried the exercise 5-4, which ask to write an function (strlen) to check whether a string (char t[]) is in the end of another string (char s[]), my solution in the strlen function is, first find the length difference, and then take this difference as an index or address of the start position in the string s, and check whether the left items are equal in two strings via while loop, the problem happened in the while loop, below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int strend(char *s, char *t)

int main()
{
    char s[] = "abcd";
    char t[] = "cd";
    printf("%d", strend(s,t));
}

/* if the string t is founded in the end of string s, return 1, otherwise return 0*/
int strend(char *s, char *t)
{
    int start;
    char *p;
    start = strlen(s) - strlen(t); /*get the length difference of two string*/
    p = &s[start];                 /*set the position of pointer p*/
    while (*p++ == *t++)
        ;
    if (*t == '\0' && *p == '\0')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I also tried the code in the online process flow (attched picture below), when the program run to the while loop ( while (*p++ == *t++)), the pointer p can not move forward in the string s, could any one kindly please help me to figure out what is wrong? thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl8nT.jpg)

Comment: @user3121023  I could understand what you say for the pointer increment, but before the while loop, p = &s[start] made the pointer p point to the s[2], which is 'c', and in this paticular case , the last two chracters in s and t in the main() are the same, in the while loop, if pointer p and t could increment correctly, then both of these pointers will point to the '\0' at the last, then the if condition will be true and return 1, but it is not, the p pointer in the while loop cannot be increased properly, and the result is return 0, this is my question.

Comment: Even the second edition of K&R is pretty old now.  It predates the publication of the first international C language specification (and we're coming up on the fifth of those).  It's an interesting read, but I do not recommend it as a textbook for learning modern C.

Comment: @user3121023 you are right, finally, it will be '\0' == '\0', but since the whole program seems not fall into endless loop, just output a wrong result, but what will happen in the while loop? will p++ and t++ keep moving and out of range and something out of control happens?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, modern C is largely a superset of what's presented in K&R, isn't it? In my opinion, it is an awesome book. Everybody should read it and do all the exercises. Then the world would be a better place, and there would be fewer boring questions on SO :-).

Comment: *Largely*, @Peter, but not *entirely*.  Some language features and standard library features have been removed.  Others are now deprecated or obsolescent.  And a lot has been added, clarified, and / or tweaked.  K&R is a fine book, but not (any more) the one from which anyone new to C should initially learn the language.